# How to transfer file from PC to Windows Phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, emulation

I trying to put a zip file from my PC into a Windows Phone 7 emulator for testing purposes. I try to find ways through internet, but I can't seem to find it. Can anyone help me in this? Sorry if it is a dump question.

Comment: What would you like to do with this zip file? Do you need to access it from within your app?

Comment: @ChristiaanV, Yeah, one of the purpose is to unzip a zip file.

Answer (score 2):

To enable the transfer of file to Isolated Storage (on the phone or emulator) the SDK now comes with the [Isolated Storage Explorer Tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh286408%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) which enables the transfer of files to or from IsolatedStorage from your PC.

Answer (score 0):

You can add it as a resource of the program you deploy on the emulator.

You can also put it in a folder accessible from an http server and download it using IE within the emulator.

Answer (score 0):

As Guillaume says, you could bundle it into your XAP file and deploy it that way.  The question is how often will the zip file change?  Deploying it that way will require you to resubmit to the Marketplace each time the zip file changes and that can take a while to approve.  If the file will never change, then bundle it into the XAP.

If the file is likely to change often, my preferred option would be to download the file from a web server.  That way you can make sure you always have up to date data in the zip file.  It also allows for the file to be updated using code you have already written, saving dev effort as well.

Answer (score 0):

Like Matt said, Isolated Storage Explorer is your answer. Shameless plug, but see if this post helps :)

http://www.jeffblankenburg.com/2011/11/16/31-days-of-mango-day-16-isolated-storage-explorer/

Thanks!